# mapping byte[] in Hibernate and adding file chunk by chunk

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I have web service which receives 100 Mb video file by chunks

```
public void addFileChunk(Long fileId, byte[] buffer)
```

How can I store this file in Postgresql database using hibernate?

Using regular JDBC is very straight forward. I would use the following code inside my web service method:

```
 LargeObject largeObject = largeObjectManager.Open(fileId, LargeObjectManager.READWRITE);
                    int size = largeObject.Size();
                    largeObject.Seek(size);
                    largeObject.Write(buffer);
                    largeObject.Close();
```

How can I achieve the same functionality using Hibernate? and store this file by chunk?

Storing each file chunk in separate row as bytea seems to me not so smart idea. Pease advice.

Comment: Why don't you simply bypass Hibernate for that?

Comment: Because this is Spring integrated Web Service and I already have Hibernate and Transaction management bean injectedand widely used across other methods. so I don't want to open new JDBC connection only for storing this file.

Answer (score 1):

its now advisable to store 100MB files in database. I would instead store them in the filesystem, but considering transactions are active, employing Servlets seems reasonable.

1. process http request so that file (received one) is stored in some temporal location.
2. open transaction, persist file metadata including temporal location, close transaction
3. using some external process which will monitor temporal files, transfer this file to its final destination from which it will be available to user through some Servlet.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be adviseable to store them as large objects in PostgreSQL.  The LOB interface gives you a filesystem-like streaming interface, so you can chunk on input or output as you desire.  It works well and you could even create indexes to index offsets of important data if you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

see http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/PostgreSQLAndBLOBs

Yeah byteas would be bad.  Hibernate has a way to continue to use large objects and you get to keep the streaming interface.